# btn-lg class doesn't work, using bootstrap3

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to Bootstrap3, and I am trying to apply class to a button.
Here is part of my code:

```
<body>
<div id="page">
    <header class="container">
            <div id="menu" class="navbar navbar-default">

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Menu</button>

                <div id="logo">
                    <a href="."><h4>The Big Lebowski</h4></a>
                </div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href=".">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    </header>
```

The problem is: the btn-lg class doesn't apply to the button, however btn-primary works fine.

Comment: Work find into a fiddle with the provided code: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/15556/)

Comment: Check your css on page may be has overwrite it. That's works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are applying "btn" wich is the same as btn-medium
It will work like this

```
<button type="button" class="btn-lg btn-primary">
```

Comment: it work even in the provided way as you can see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/15556/)

Comment: @StefanoSaitta so what seems to be the problem?

Comment: i don't actually know but your is not an answer. The problem could be somewhere else

Comment: Did you correctilly add the bootstrap css in the page <head>?

@StefanoSaitta    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">